# How do I limit the table width to the containing element (or screen)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to show tabular data using a `table`, but it will be within a fluid layout; I want to have a it fill the entire available width but not to expand horizontally beyond maximum screen-width, such that the `body` does not get a horizontal scrollbar.  Instead the too wide `td` elements shall get the scrollbar.

In the example there is `DATA` in the `table`, the `table` has `border:1px solid black` and the output shall be for easy parsing when piped from curl as well (hence the `white-space:pre`);  The `div` is just the normal CSS layout helper, if possible let's get rid of that, too!

The important part is, that it shall be no fixed pixel width layout type, and the `table` shall be smaller than the available width in case **the data** does not need that much room.  So to sum it up, a plain table which just does not get wider than the screen.  Ideally the `table` would only stretch the parental element until the `max-width` of that enclosing element is reached and then do not get wider.

In `Chrome`, with something I consider to be an evil hack, I got to keep the `table` at the maximum width available and to display the scrollbars on the `td` if needed.  However this does not work for FF, nor is that solution something which can be considered a correct one.

Following example of that can be found at https://hydra.geht.net/table-quirx.html for a while:

```css
.nw             { white-space:nowrap }
.quirx div      { width:100%; max-width:100%; white-space:pre }
.quirx td       { max-width:90px; border:1px solid black }
.quirx td+td    { max-width:500px; overflow:auto }
table.quirx     { width:100%; max-width:100%; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse }
td              { align:left; max-width:100% }
```

```html
<head>
<title>Obey max-width for table</title>

</head>
<body>
<table summary="" class="quirx"><tr><td colspan="3">
Just some info
</td></tr><tr><td>KEY</td><td><div>DATA (which might contain long lines PRE formatted) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
```

Note that the "colspan=3" is no error here, in my app sometimes a third column may show up, this cannot be known at the time the `table` header is output.  (Some style things are redundant, too.)

The trick above is, that the `td`'s `max-width` together are smaller than the usual screen (`590px`) and the `table` then is stretched to the given `width`, which is 100%.  As the `td`s do not stretch beyond the screen, the inner `div`'s `overflow` property can work as expected.  However in FF it does not work this way, neither with `width` nor with `max-width` (which is probably due to their `inline`-status).  In `Chrome` a `width:100%` or similar does not work on the `td` nor the `tr` elements.  Note that with `max-width` one gets a more pleasant table layout than with `width` (I do not understand that difference).

Besides the bug that this only works in `Chrome`, another bug is, that the `table` uses the full screen-width even if that is not needed if there is only small **data** to display.

Some notes about that all:

- I think this here is a very basic thing and I am puzzled why it seems so hard to express with CSS
- A goal is to keep it free of any JavaScript, so only CSS with hacks
- The user can resize the window, for example from 800px to 1920px or even wider, and so the `table`'s width shall automatically follow (without JavaScript)
- It shall display good on text based browsers like `Lynx` and `w3m`, too
- Output shall not be too cluttered for easy parsing when piped from `curl`
- It shall display more or less properly on the major 4 (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari)
- It shall not break on others (it can have render bugs, but content must not be hidden)

I really have no idea how to archive that.  Perhaps it's a FAQ, but I was unable to spot a solution myself.

Answer (score 20):

I'm including some markup below that tests the HTML/CSS to achieve what I believe you want.

There is a fixed-width cell style `.fixedcell` and fluid width cell style `.fluidcell`. I've set a fixed width (75px for this example) simply to illustrate things better.

The fluid width ones have `width:auto` so they fill the width of the remaining table space; they also importantly have `white-space:nowrap` so the text doesn't expand the cell height-wise (`white-space:pre` works too); and finally they have `overflow:hidden` so the text doesn't overflow the width and make things ugly, alternatively you could set **overflow:scroll** for it to have a scrollbar in those cells when/if necessary.

The table is set to be 100% width so it will expand to fit the screen/etc as needed. And the important thing regarding the table's style is the `table-layout:fixed`, this makes the table adhere to the layout of the page rather than auto-sizing itself based on its own content (`table-layout:auto`).

I also added some borders to help illustrate the boundaries of the table and cells.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table with auto-width sizing and overflow hiding.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {width:100%; border:solid 1px red; table-layout:fixed;}
        table td {border:solid 1px green;}
        .fixedcell {width:75px;}
        .fluidcell {width:auto; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Table with one fluid column:
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="fixedcell">row 1</td>
            <td class="fluidcell">a whole bunch of content could go here and it still needs to fit nice into the cell without mucking things up</td>
            <td class="fixedcell">fixie</td>
            <td class="fixedcell">another</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    Table with two fluid columns:
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="fixedcell">row 1</td>
            <td class="fluidcell">a whole bunch of content could go here and it still needs to fit nice into the cell without mucking things up</td>
            <td class="fluidcell">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td>
            <td class="fixedcell">fixie</td>
            <td class="fixedcell">another</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested it in several modern browsers and seemed to work correctly in each.

PS. Although tables are a no-no for page layout in general, tables are correct and encouraged for tabular data layout.